# ODP to SWF to OGG Animation Problem

Tags: video, libreoffice

I created a small .odp file containing some simple text animations using LibreOffice that I exported to SWF.  Now I want to use the text animation in Pitivi to add a short soundtrack to the animation (audio taken from a different video).  The problem that I have is that I can not find any online / offline tool that can convert the .swf (or .odp) and include the animations successfully.  Either an error occurs during conversion or whatever converter eliminates the text animations, returning a video of static text (no animation).  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and LibreOffice 5 and Pitivi.. . anyone have any ideas? I need to convert the swf (or odp) to either ogg webm or mp4 for use in Pitivi.

Thanks